# Very new to python and struggling to use this API

Tags: python, api, finance, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

How do I extract a specific data point from the `"ticker.financials"`. Say I wanted to assign operating income in 2020 on that chart to `"Operating_Income"`

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import requests
import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

ticker.financials
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: it gives you `pandas dataframe` so you have to learn how to use `dataframe`

Comment: Sorry about the screenshot, the problem is I don't have an error in my code I just don't know how to approach the problem at all.

Comment: you get `pandas dataframe` and you should learn `pandas`. It is powerfull module and it has many functions to work with data without `for`-loops. As for me it could be `ticker.financials.loc["Operating Income"]` but at this moment `ticker.financials` gives me only empty dataframe so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
ticker.financials.iloc[8]["Operating_Income"]
```

You can look at iloc property on pandas documentation for selecting specific cells.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice. What ended up working was : ticker.financials.iloc[8,0] to extract operating income from 2020-06-30